# Как получить другую страницы через js

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить страницу(html) которая находиться на другом домене через js.

Comment: другой домен вами контролируется ?

 * да - CORS
 * нет - proxy

Comment: другой домен не контролируется, в смысле прокси?

Comment: у себя прокси в http, с него ajax, по другому никак.

Answer (score 1):

На одном js вы не получите html-код страницы.

Отправляйте ajax-запрос на свой сервер. А тот в свою очередь пусть отправляет curl-запросы к любой странице любого домена и возвращает результат, например, в json. Далее на js уже работайте с html страницы, если вам так нужно.

Или вы хотите в iframe отобразить ту страницу?